# How do i get my custom mob to drop items with lores and have 2 diffrent attributes? (Minecraft 1.16.4 java)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im making a boss type of a mob in my server and i couldnt find how to make a mob drop items with lores and 2 attributes. ( i need an illusioner to drop a skeleton head that is named "skull of the chosen) has a lore (Potassium) and has attributes (8 max_health, 3.1 attack_damage)) pls help

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the mob's `DeathLootTable` NBT to reference a custom loot table. Inside that loot table, you can then use the `minecraft:set_attributes`, `minecraft:set_name` and `minecraft:set_lore` item modifiers to apply attribute modifiers and change the name and lore of the skull item.

Here's an example: let's say that you have a loot table named `boss_mob.json` inside your `data/example/loot_tables/entities` folder (you would refer to the loot table as `example:entities/boss_mob`), and that your mob (in this case, an illusioner) has the `example.boss_mob` tag (either added by the `/tag` command or the `Tags` NBT)

Here's how the setup would look like:

(the command to modify the `DeathLootTable` NBT of all the entities that have the `example.boss_mob` tag)

```
execute as @e[tag = example.boss_mob] run data modify entity @s DeathLootTable set value "example:entities/boss_mob"
```

(the contents of the `data/example/loot_tables/entities/boss_mob.json` loot table)

```
{
    "pools": [
        {
            "rolls": 1,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "minecraft:item",
                    "name": "minecraft:skeleton_skull",
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "minecraft:set_attributes",
                            "modifiers": [
                                {
                                    "attribute": "minecraft:generic.max_health",
                                    "name": "",
                                    "amount": 8,
                                    "operation": "addition",
                                    "slot": "head"
                                },
                                {
                                    "attribute": "minecraft:generic.attack_damage",
                                    "name": "",
                                    "amount": 3.1,
                                    "operation": "addition",
                                    "slot": "head"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "function": "minecraft:set_name",
                            "name": {
                                "text": "Skull of the Chosen",
                                "italic": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "function": "minecraft:set_lore",
                            "lore": [
                                {
                                    "text": "Potassium",
                                    "color": "gray",
                                    "italic": false
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```